# Как вывести весь товар и подставить фотографию в случаи ее отсутствия от категории через sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как вывести весь товар и сделать проверку, если у товара нет фотографии, то подставлять фотографию от категории

Есть две таблицы

```
Prods
id,title,category_id,photo

Category
id,title,photo
```

Сейчас получилось лишь вывести название категории у товара, не могу понять как сделать проверку на фотографию и в случаи отсутствия подставить из категории

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.title `Название товара`, 
       p.photo `Фотография товара`, 
       c.id `category_id`, 
       c.title `Название категории`, 
       c.photo `Фотография категории` 
FROM `products` p 
INNER JOIN `categories` c ON c.id = p.category_id
```

Comment: *как сделать проверку на фотографию и в случаи отсутствия подставить из категории* А какое значение будет в `p.photo` "в случаи отсутствия"?

Comment: В случаи отсутствия в поле будет пусто ''

Comment: Пусто - это строка нулевой длины или NULL?

Comment: Строка нулевой длины, не NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.title `Название товара`, 
       CASE WHEN p.photo = ''
            THEN c.photo
            ELSE p.photo
            END `Фотография`, 
       c.id `category_id`, 
       c.title `Название категории`
FROM `products` p 
INNER JOIN `categories` c ON c.id = p.category_id
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает